# Google Geocoding API : Colombian Addresses issues / How to GeoCode Address intersections?

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the Google GeoCodng API ,
I'm facing troubles trying to geocode addresses from Colombia,, for example 'Carrera 8 # 27 - 06, Santa Marta, MAD, CO', that address means  ( Colombian notation) Street = Carrera 8 at 27 meters of Carrera 06... , The API results is a mid point of the City Santa Marta.

As an alternative, I want to ask for intersection of Carrera 8 and Carrera 06 ... but Are any way to ask for streets intersections in the Request?
something like Carrera 8 cross Carrera 06  ??

thanks, Any idea or suggestions would be great !!

Comment: Instead of `Carrera 8 cross Carrera 06`  try `Carrera 8 and Carrera 06`

Comment: IIUC this query is for an address about 27 meters away from the intersection, which is a common pattern in Colombia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a different API, this address format is supported much better by [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete), with 2 caveats (details below). If you really need to use the Geocoding API, I suggest you [report a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188871&template=788905) about this.

**Caveat 1**: The desired address may be different than you think. At least, as far as these address are supported by Place Autocomplete and Google Maps:

- Carrera 8 # **27 - 06** (your query above) is interpreted as *address **6 meters** away from the intersection of Carrera 8 and **Calle 27***.
- Carrera 8 # **6 - 27** interpreted as *address **27 meters** away from the intersection of Carrera 8 and **Calle 6*** (closer to your interpretation above).

**Caveat 2**: Results are often better when removing blank spaces around the `#` and the numbers that follow it.

With Blank spaces (`Carrera 8 # 27 - 06`): the result is "Carrera 8 #**27**" at 11.23607,-74.206259 (**on** the intersection).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Carrera%208%20%23%2027%20-%2006,%20Santa%20Marta,%20MAD,%20CO

```json
description: "Carrera 8 #27, Comuna 1, Santa Marta, Magdalena, Colombia",
place_id: "EjlDYXJyZXJhIDggIzI3LCBDb211bmEgMSwgU2FudGEgTWFydGEsIE1hZ2RhbGVuYSwgQ29sb21iaWEiMBIuChQKEglV0F19d_X0jhHxdnkgSY57xBABKhQKEgkRED6oevX0jhHJKMXdmInqZg",
types: ["street_address","geocode"]
```

**Without** Blank spaces (`Carrera 8 #27-06`) the result is "Carrera 8 #27**-6**" at 11.235968,-74.206502 (about 15 m. off the intersection).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Carrera%208%20%2327-06,%20Santa%20Marta,%20MAD,%20CO

```json
description: "Carrera 8 #27-6, Comuna 1, Santa Marta, Magdalena, Colombia",
place_id: "EjtDYXJyZXJhIDggIzI3LTYsIENvbXVuYSAxLCBTYW50YSBNYXJ0YSwgTWFnZGFsZW5hLCBDb2xvbWJpYSIwEi4KFAoSCafwXH139fSOEZgBlEk6gFM-EAYqFAoSCREQPqh69fSOEckoxd2Yiepm",
types: ["street_address","geocode"]
```

Make sure to [URL-encode parameter values like `input`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/web-services-best-practices#special-characters), because otherwise `#` *breaks* it:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Carrera%208%20#%2027%20-%2006,%20Santa%20Marta,%20MAD,%20CO

```json
description: "Carrera 8, Cali, Valle del Cauca, Colombia",
place_id: "EipDYXJyZXJhIDgsIENhbGksIFZhbGxlIGRlbCBDYXVjYSwgQ29sb21iaWEiLiosChQKEgmTf2JVTaYwjhFZP3nFcTrX2BIUChIJESedtkOmMI4R--NFJ63l3jc",
types: ["route","geocode"]
```

The result is a `route` (and not in Santa Marta) because the value of `input` is truncated to only the characters before the `#` character.